# Allow loopback application to use previous access token

Tags: access-token, loopbackjs, strongloop

In my loopback application, once i create the access token (after login), it remains valid in my application unless application stops. when application restarted it is not allowing previous access token. How can i make previous access token validate even after restarting the application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your access token is getting stored by default in loopback `memory`. Therefore, it persists  only until the application is restarted.

> open server/model-config.json

```
"AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  }
```

This is the `initial configuration` of the `Access Tokens`. See here the storage datasource is `db` which is loopback memory. You need to change this to your MongoDB or some other storage

You need to store `Access Tokens` in the database rather in the memory.

For example lets store this to the mongoDb storage.

1. Assuming you already have mongodb installed in your system. Install the mongodb connector. In console type

   `npm install loopback-connector-mongodb`
2. Now configure the `server/datasources.json` file. Add this line to this file.

   `"mongodb": {
       "host": "0.0.0.0",
       "port": 27017,
       "database": "MONGODB DATABASE NAME",
       "password": "MONGODB PASSWORD",
       "name": "MONGODB NAME",
       "connector": "mongodb",
       "user": "YOUR USER NAME"
   }`
3. Open `server/model-config.json`. change this `db` to `mongodb`

   `"AccessToken": {
     "dataSource": "mongodb",
     "public": false
   }`

Now run the loopback server `Acces Tokens will be there even after restarting the application.